# If statement not responding to int input with neopixel

Tags: python

I'm having a really weird error. When entering an int to select a color, the variable saves but doesn't respond correctly to the if statement.

```
print("Select color by typing the corresponding number")
print("Red[1]")
....
userColor = input("Enter number: ")
```

So that's the setup for the input, however when I type 1 into the console the color wont change

```
if userColor == 1:
    print("If you see this code is activated")
    pixels.fill((255,0,0))
    pixels.show
```

The console wont show the activated line and the color doesn't change, I put a print under the input to check and make sure it is saving as 1 and it seems to be. I'm sure its something small I'm just looking over. The lights are wired properly and are blue from a previous program.

Should I switch the variable to a char or string? or am I missing something in syntax, thanks!

This is my first stack overflow question so if its formatted wrong I apologize.

Comment: Do you need parentheses after `pixels.show`? It should be a function so I would assume so.

Comment: @Seth yup just saw that.

Comment: @khelwood do I need to declare it before? `int userColor` for example?

Comment: @MatthewMcDaniel See the linked duplicate.

Comment: @khelwood That worked! Thank you.